# Cannot install Eclipse Perl plugin

Tags: eclipse, perl, maven, eclipse-plugin, epic

I am not able to install EPIC in my eclipse. The "Problem Occurred" dialog says:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://www.epic-ide.org/updates/testing/plugins/org.epic.doc_0.7.1.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://www.epic-ide.org/updates/testing/plugins/org.epic.lib_0.7.1.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://www.epic-ide.org/updates/testing/plugins/org.epic.source_0.7.2.jar.
Read timed out
```

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Luna

Comment: And what operating system?

Answer (score 1):

I had no issues.
I installed **Eclipse (Luna) IDE for Java EE Developers** on Windows 7.
Did you use the EPIC download site at [EPIC download](http://www.epic-ide.org/download.php) for the EPIC software?

[image]
[image]
[image]